# How to set border radius ant design

Tags: reactjs, ant-design-pro

I am using ant design and cant figure out how to change login forms username and password box border-radius.

Here is a link to the login form in question.
https://codesandbox.io/s/rx2qf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set **borderRadius** with inline style would work

```
style={{borderRadius: '10px'}}
```

```
<Input
  prefix={<LockOutlined className="site-form-item-icon" />}
  type="password"
  placeholder="Password"
  style={{borderRadius: '10px'}}
/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check this in their docs
https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme#Ant-Design-Less-variables

You can set **@border-radius-base** if you are using less

If not just set it by yourself in css file

```css
.ant-input-affix-wrapper {
   border-radius: 5px;   // or other value
}
```